# NHibernate custom connection string configuration

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, ado.net

I have a c# library project, that i configured using nhibernate, and I like people to be able to import this project and use the project. This project has FrontController that does all the work.

I have a connection string in hibernate config file and in app.config file of another project.

it would be nice for anyone to be able to set the connection string into this library project and use it. such as through a method which will take the connectiong string as parameter. or when creating a new instance of FrontController to pass the connection string to constructor. or if you have a better idea.

How to do this?

I d like this class library to use the same database of the project that s imported.

How to set hibernate connection string programatically?

same idea for log4net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you build your `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration` and session factory. It can be as simple as this:

```
public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory(string connectionString) {
    var cfg = new Configuration()
                .AddProperties(new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    {Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof (SQLite20Driver).FullName},
                    {Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof (ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName},
                    {Environment.Dialect, typeof (SQLiteDialect).FullName},
                    {Environment.ConnectionProvider, typeof (DriverConnectionProvider).FullName},
                    {Environment.ConnectionString, connectionString},
                })
                .AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with log4net though.